# Salesforce: how to display record amount in a matrix report in separate column?

Tags: salesforce, report, display

I have a matrix report with two fields on the vertical axis and one on the horizontal axis. Any way to have the record count as a separate column to the right of the report, instead of a row below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, you can't to display it as you wish in Matrix report, but you can try a Summary Report for a separate display of Record count.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I'll check, can I change report type to Summary report or not.